# What is the optimal value of limit_phrases for the summary method in pyTextRank

Tags: python, spacy, summary, pytextrank

I am summarizing documents using TextRank pipeline in SpaCy. I need to summarize both long and short documents. Can you suggest a good approach to choose the right parameter of limit_phrases?

this is the approach I am currently using, but I am sure it can be improved:

```
import spacy
import pytextrank

nlp = spacy.load(spacy_model)
nlp.add_pipe("textrank", last=True)

# Process the input text
doc = nlp(text)

doc_sentences = len(list(doc.sents))
print(f'Number of document sentences = {doc_sentences}')
limit_sentences = int(doc_sentences * percentage)
limit_phrases = int(limit_sentences * 2)

top_sentences = doc._.textrank.summary(limit_phrases=limit_phrases, limit_sentences=limit_sentences, preserve_order=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal values for `limit_phrases` will depend strongly on your content. Do you have any kind of benchmark against which you could run test, essentially doing a grid search to find a reasonable setting for this parameter?

FWIW, I'm one of the authors of `pytextrank`, and this is really good question. There's no analytic way to determining how to set this parameter, as far as our team knows.

Comment: thanks @Paco for the good advice :) 
at the moment I have not yet implemented a method to evaluate the output summaries. I was thinking of using the summaries generated by gpt4 as a benchmark (although I know they are not extractive). Do you have any advice regarding setting the benchmark and evaluating the model?

Comment: That could be a good way to bootstrap this, by using a larger model and generating examples of abstractive/generative summarizations.

If you have a lot of this work, I'd recommend a tool to manage, such as Argilla https://argilla.io/